# Uncaught type error: cannot read property persist of undefined with react-bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I'm implementing a [react-bootsrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#carousels) carousel with react-redux and I'm getting the error in the title.

I'm using a controlled carousel and the error message appears when the carousel changes a slide automatically.

When the user clicks prev. next buttons and changes it manually all seems to be ok.

I don't get it should I add persist as props or options to props or similar?

Here's my code:

container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import store from 'store/configureStore'
import Slides from 'components/SlideShow'
import { getInitalSlides, handleSelect } from 'actions/SlidesActions'

class Home extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        index: null,
        direction: null
    }
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)    

static fetchData({ store }) {
        return store.dispatch(getInitalSlides())
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getInitalSlides()
    }

handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
        //alert(e)
        this.props.handleSelect(selectedIndex, e)
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <Slides 
        slides={this.props.slides}   
        getInitialState={this.state.index} 
        getInitialStateD={this.state.direction}
        slidesControl={this.handleSelect}
        />
        <div><Link to="/question">to question</Link></div>
        <div><Link to="/posts">to posts</Link></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  const { slides, handleSelect } = state

  return { slides: state.slides, onSelect: state.handleSelect } 
}

export { Home }
export default connect(mapStateToProps { getInitalSlides, handleSelect})(Home)
```

and here is the relevant bit in the component:

```
    render() {

    return (
      <Carousel 
      activeIndex={this.props.getInitialState} 
      direction={this.props.getInitialStateD} 
      onSelect={(selectedIndex,e)=>this.props.slidesControl(selectedIndex,e)}
      >
      {

      this.props.slides.map((s)=>{
              let id = s.get('id')
              let title = s.get('title')
              let image = s.get('image')
              let alt = s.get('alt')
              let caption = s.get('caption')
              return(

                    <Carousel.Item key={id} >
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt={s.get('alt')} src={image} alt={alt}/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                      <h3>{title}</h3>
                      <p>{caption}</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                  </Carousel.Item>

              )
      }) 



    }
    </Carousel>)
  }
}
```

Edit: 
Here is the relevant react-bootstrap carousel code (where the error is thrown)

```
  var onSelect = this.props.onSelect;

  if (onSelect) {
    if (onSelect.length > 1) {
      // React SyntheticEvents are pooled, so we need to remove this event
      // from the pool to add a custom property. To avoid unnecessarily
      // removing objects from the pool, only do this when the listener
      // actually wants the event.
      e.persist();
      e.direction = direction;

      onSelect(index, e);
    } else {
      onSelect(index);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you use event parameter `e` in your `handleSelect` method?

Comment: you mean in the action creator?

Comment: export const HANDLE_SELECT = Symbol('HANDLE_SELECT')
export function handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    return {
     index: selectedIndex,
     direction: e.direction,
     //persist: e.persist,
     type: HANDLE_SELECT
    }
}

Comment: yes, in function that is passed to `Carousel` as `onSelect` callback.

Comment: Yeah as you can see above in my action creator which is passed to my onSelect I'm using it to set the direction (e.direction). Not sure of how to use the e.persist though if that is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I analyzed `Carousel.js` code of `react-bootstrap` and I suspect it is issue in `react-bootstrap` library itself.

[There is this line triggering change in Carousel.js code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Carousel.js#L141):

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(this.next, this.props.interval);
```

`this.next` method expects parameter of type `SynteticEvent`, but none is passed from `setTimeout` call. That exlpains your error message: `...persist of undefined...`.

The issue was probably hidden for a long time, [but was exposed with this commit](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/commit/ed4ee103d389a8091ab03b2a5e17992c8f1c8f39), where event parameter is actually used by Carousel.ja code itself.

So I recommend to create react-bootstrap Github issue and in the meantime downgrade to version that doesn't contain mentioned commit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and trouble. I will try to post a github issue.

Comment: I think the arrow function binds it

Comment: I deleted side note

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue link in the project's github page. Seems there's a fix coming up:

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2029